# How to replace #N/A in whole sheet while each column has different Formula?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet which contains many columns. I have applied different formulas on  Each column. Now many cells are giving #N/A error. I want to replace #N/A in whole sheet with blank cell or 0 value.

I tried to find solution but solutions available can be applied only on one column having one uniform formula.
How i can replace #N/A in whole sheet into 0 Value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

> I have applied different formulas on Each column

wrap your formulas into `IFNA()`

if you want 0 values wrap it like this:

```
=IFNA(your_formula_here; 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such feature

If you really want to 'hide' the #N/A display, you may consider setting both text and cell color to white using conditional formatting rules i